# Rewrite whole domain (including directories) to new domain root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect one domain, including all subdirectories/files to the root of a new domain.

I have this thus far

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldexample\.com\.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldexample\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/newexample\.com\.au\/" [R=301,L]
```

However this rule seems to include any /directory from the old url

Answer (score 0):

To redirect everything from old domain to the root of new domain, change your rule's pattern to the following

```
^(.*)$
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work for me. Rule has been edited to be

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldexample\.com\.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldexample\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/newexample\.com\.au\/" [R=301,L]`

Is that correct?